# Start an intent when another intent has finished

Tags: android, email, android-intent, photo, wait

I have some troubles in my Android app. I need to start an intent when another intent has finished. The problem is that both intents are launched at the same time (i don't know why). Here is my code:

In this dialog i ask if the user wants to take a photo before send an email (and of course i want to send the email with the photo). Ok?

```
private Dialog comprobarFoto() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

        builder.setMessage("¿Desea adjuntar una foto con este mensaje de su posición actual?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Si", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                hacerFoto();
                enviarMail(true);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                enviarMail(false);
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }); 
        return builder.create();    
    }
```

Here is the method where I create the email

```
private void enviarMail(boolean foto) {
        if(locMail!=null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
            i.setType("message/rfc822");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Quiero que sepas donde estoy!"); 
            if(foto && fotoPath != null && fotoPath.length()>0) {
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(fotoPath));
            }
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hola!\n Estoy en la dirección:" +
                    "\n" + localizarDireccion() +
                    "\n\n(lat= " + dfmail.format(locMail.getLatitude()) + ")" +
                    "\n(long=" + dfmail.format(locMail.getLongitude()) + ") " +
                    "\n \n[Enviado desde GeoLocation]" );  
            startActivity(i);
        }else{
            dialogError("No se puede encontrar una localización").show();
        }
    }
```

And this is the method where I take the photo:

```
private void hacerFoto() {  
        //El gran quebradero de cabeza aquí fue que no le daba permisos a la aplicación para escribir en la tarjeta. En el manifest se puede comprobar esta directiva
        File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () + "/GeoLocation/images"); 
        if(!carpeta.exists()){
            carpeta.mkdirs();
        }
        fotoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/GeoLocation/images/GLPict"+cogerFecha()+".jpg";
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Uri output = Uri.fromFile(new File(fotoPath));
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
```

The problem is that the intent of sendMail (enviarMail) doesn't wait to the first method takePhoto (hacerFoto) has finished. Is there some method that let me say to the sendMail intent to wait until the method takePhoto has finished?

Thanks for all and SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start first intent like `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` and when this will return `onActivityResult` gets called, and from there you can start the second intent.

edit :: 
do it like this ::

```
private Dialog comprobarFoto() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

    builder.setMessage("¿Desea adjuntar una foto con este mensaje de su posición actual?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Si", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            hacerFoto();
      ///////////// do not call enviarMail(true) from here, call it from onActivityResult, see below //////////////////
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            enviarMail(false);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }); 
    return builder.create();    
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode,int resultCode,Intent intent)
{
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        if( reqCode == 1)
            enviarMail(true); //////// call from here ///////   
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i dont get it.. sorry... im looking some example on internet but i dont understand when i have to call onActivityResult.

Comment: @user1428366 you don't need to call onActivityResult(), it will get called automatically once the first intent returns, you just need to start second intent from onActivityResult().

Comment: OH GOOOD!!! it works!! HAHAHAH now i understand the reason of the int in the startActivityForResults... then, making a quick summary... when i call startActivityForResults, the program check into onActivityResuls with the int code. Once that first activity has finished, automatically call the intent asociated to that int number on the onActivityResult method... isn´t that? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the onFinish() or onStop() to initiate the next intent?

Comment: But i'm not running an activity. it's an intent. Can I do that? How? Sorry.. i'm new developing in android